# How to return an array with the first 2 elements in an object whose value properties are an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I just want to return an array containing the first and second objects of the element.

The next 2 elements will be repeated after traversing the keys

Given the following object:

```
const object = {
  a: [
    { name: "John", age: 32 },
    { name: "David", age: 23 },
    { name: "Justin", age: 28 },
    { name: "Arnauld", age: 35 }
  ],
  b: [
    { name: "Ivan", age: 18 },
    { name: "Nekko", age: 13 },
    { name: "Lena", age: 25 }
  ],
  c: [
    { name: "Ann", age: 19 },
    { name: "Nick", age: 14 }
  ]
};
```

the result I want is

```
[
  { name: "John", age: 32 },
  { name: "David", age: 23 },
  { name: "Ivan", age: 18 },
  { name: "Nekko", age: 13 },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19 },
  { name: "Nick", age: 14 },
  { name: "Justin", age: 28 },
  { name: "Arnauld", age: 35 },
  { name: "Lena", age: 25 }
]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not really understanding the question. Also try to provide your own attempt(s) if possible. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I have updated the question above

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what needs to be done, the answer will look like this:

```js
const array = {
    a: [
        {name: "AA", age: 18},
        {name: "BB", age: 22},
        {name: "cc", age: 22}
    ],
    b: [
        {name: "CC", age: 18},
        {name: "DD", age: 13}
    ],
    c: [
        {name: "EE", age: 18},
        {name: "FF", age: 14}
    ]
};

const result = Object.values(array).reduce((buff, array) => {
    buff.push(array[0], array[1]);
    return buff;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code I would like the format below
a[0]
a[1]
b[0]
b[1]
c[0]
c[1]
a[0]
Or you can check the question I just updated above